# What is time data type in redshift external table?

Tags: amazon-redshift

the create statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE model.fixed_hours (
 id int,
 something_time time,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hudi.hadoop.HoodieParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION .......;
```

results this error:

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: Unsupported data type "pg_catalog.time" for
> external table creation

what can I use in Redshift as data type to store time format **03:13:00**

Answer (score -1):

Valid data types in Redshift are:

```
SMALLINT (INT2)

INTEGER (INT, INT4)

BIGINT (INT8)

DECIMAL (NUMERIC)

REAL (FLOAT4)

DOUBLE PRECISION (FLOAT8)

BOOLEAN (BOOL)

CHAR (CHARACTER)

VARCHAR (CHARACTER VARYING)

VARBYTE (CHARACTER VARYING) – can be used with Parquet and ORC data files, and only with non-partition columns.

DATE – can be used only with text, Parquet, or ORC data files, or as a partition column.

TIMESTAMP
```

For DATE, you can use the formats as described following. For month values represented using digits, the following formats are supported:

mm-dd-yyyy For example, 05-01-2017. This is the default.

yyyy-mm-dd, where the year is represented by more than 2 digits. For example, 2017-05-01.

For month values represented using the three letter abbreviation, the following formats are supported:

mmm-dd-yyyy For example, may-01-2017. This is the default.

dd-mmm-yyyy, where the year is represented by more than 2 digits. For example, 01-may-2017.

yyyy-mmm-dd, where the year is represented by more than 2 digits. For example, 2017-may-01.

More info here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEFORMAT_and_TIMEFORMAT_strings.html